# How to disable carousel card pagination in MS Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, chatbot, adaptive-cards, azure-qna-maker

We are able to see a different carousel card pagination style in the **MS Team channel** (Desktop App) for the past two days.

[image]

**Old Design:**

[image]

**Note:** *Displaying QnA maker ( Not Custom QnA ) multi-prompt response into the chatbot ( We are not using any custom adaptive card and by default, the carousel card pagination is generated through the framework )*.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to disable carousel card pagination in MS Teams. This is by design behaviour.

Comment: This is by design behavior then how to handle multilingual? As of now, business point out this issue in a multilingual scenario ( It shows as English instead of French ).

Comment: We required a multilingual update?

Comment: We have change the Teams language in setting and its changing in pagination of carousel card.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwhdQ.png

Comment: As per our case instead of the ms team settings change we are switching the language in the chatbot flow itself. Let me know the fix ?

Comment: Could you please share the code snippets that how you are changing the language in chatbot flow to try at our end?

Comment: Code we can't share due to policy, The approach is to update the locale with a different language like "fr-fr" and then based on the language connect the respective knowledge base ( french language kb with multiturn ) then you will get the same issue.

Comment: Hello @RajeeshMenoth - We can localize our Teams application: Reference doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/apps-localization  Reference sample link: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/app-localization/csharp/Localization/Resources/Bots

Comment: Could you please confirm whether you are following this documentation and sending the carousel card from Teams bot ?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#carousel-collection

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft - The document is the same you can refer to my previous comment.

Comment: We got an updates from engineering team that there is no way to disable carousel card pagination in MS Teams.
Could you please raise a feature request here:
[Microsoft Teams Community](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)